# Apache Tomee SessionContext Returns 'guest' Principal

Tags: jsf-2, ejb-3.0, apache-tomee

I have an EJB deployeed in apache tomee however `context.getCallerPrincipal().getName();` always returns '`guest`' user no matter who has been authenticated in the web module. The correct user is capture correctly in my JSF managed bean.

**EJB**

```
@Stateless()
@DeclareRoles(value = {"ROLE_USER"})
public class StudentFacade extends AbstractFacade<Student> {

    @Resource
    private SessionContext context;
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "tomeePU")
    private EntityManager em;

    public StudentFacade() {
        super(Student.class);
    }

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)

    public void save(Student student) {

        System.out.println("Username in EJB "+context.getCallerPrincipal().getName());
        //prints 'guest' user
        em.persist(student);
    }

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.SUPPORTS)
    public Student getById(Integer id) {
        return em.find(Student.class, id);
    }

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }
}
```

**Method in jsf managed bean**

```
 public void save(AjaxBehaviorEvent ajaxBehaviorEvent) {
        try {
            studentFacade.save(student);
            Principal p = JsfUtil.getCurrentHttpRequest().getUserPrincipal();
            System.out.println("UserName Is " + p.getName());//Works fine
            setStudent(new Student());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
        }
```

What are additional tomee configurations to make propagate correct Principal to the ejb?
Thanks.